# Regression model selection for gross motor function analysis

Tags: regression, logistic, ordered-logit

I am using the Gross Motor Function Measure (https://www.canchild.ca/en/measures/gmfm.asp) to explore the relationship between age and gross motor function in a cohort of children. I have chosen ordinal logistic over simple linear regression to analysis the data given that the scale of individual item is ordinal (0,1,2,3). I wonder if the ordinal model would work if the total score (range 0-198, 66 items) is being analysed, and if not which model(s) would you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kingsley

Answer (score 0):

Since the response variable is the total score, not individual items themselves, it is the total score distribution that matters. The problem seems suited for linear regression assuming homoscedasticity assumption has been met. Which might be an issue because it is likely that with age the extent of departure in motor function will increase (ie differences between highest- and lowest-performing individuals are amplified). But aside from that, simple linear reg, multiple regression and non-linear regression have all been used to model this, if you check googlescholar.

Comment: Thanks katya. The residual plot of the multiple linear regression (http://i58.tinypic.com/2n9alpk.jpg) shows an interesting pattern - the points at the left lower corner are truncated. I am not sure if this is acceptable.